# determining timeouts / retry attempts in distributed systems

Tags: optimization, distributed-systems

**Is there a methodical procedure for determining the optimal timeout / retry strategy for dealing with a remote server that handles processes responses for requests, given some probability distribution of response time?**

For example, suppose I have a client program which requests a web page from some server, and I know roughly the probability distribution of its response time, e.g. 95% of the time I'll get a response with a [gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution), and 5% of the time my request will get lost and a response never sent. So maybe 80% of the time I'll get a response within 100 milliseconds, and 90% of the time I'll get a response within 500 milliseconds.

On one hand, I could set a timeout of 500 milliseconds and retry with another request after then. Or I could set a timeout of 100 milliseconds. A longer timeout means I have more chance of success, but I have to wait longer. A shorter timeout means I can reduce my wait time potentially, at the cost of increasing the chance of failure (I give up too early; the server will respond). Or I could just send two identical requests up front and take whichever response arrives first -- this seems like it might be the optimal strategy, but something seems wrong here. (why then wouldn't I send 100 identical requests? I guess I'm not modeling the fact that lots of additional requests would clog the server queue.)

Please help; I know this is a fairly general question, but I have no idea where to look for more information of this type. I never took any classes on distributed systems in college + am trying to improve responsiveness of a client program.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I have found to this problem is using **rolling percentile latency**. The optimal timeout will shift based on hardware, network configuration and the state of the operating system. Therefore it cannot be fixed/established beforehand, but approximated at runtime. The typical practice in industry is to maintain P95 and P99 response times. These are durations in which 95% and 99% of requests complete respectively over some time duration. So you could perhaps store the last hour of request times, and if the current request is longer than 95% of the others in the last rolling 60 minutes, then you deem that a timeout.

This will adapt and gradually become more strict if response times are fast, and more lenient if they become slow.

You can read more about percentile latency [here](https://medium.com/@ankur_anand/an-in-depth-introduction-to-99-percentile-for-programmers-22e83a00caf).